# Why GET_X_LPARAM does return an absolute position on mouse wheel?

Tags: c++, events, mousewheel, mouse-position

I override the `WndProc` method of my Window where I handle Windows messages.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

In order to get the position of the mouse when I catch the left button down event (`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) I use the following code:

```
auto x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
auto y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

And this works well. I am able to get the relative position of the mouse on my window. But I have a problem when I catch the mouse wheel event (`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`). In this case it seems that the above macros return the abousulte position of the mouse within my screen.

How can I get the relative position of the mouse even on the mouse wheel event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617.aspx) indeed carries screen-based coordinates in `lParam`. That's by design.

To convert into client-based coordinates, you can use [ScreenToClient()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952.aspx):

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);
// 'pt' now contains client-based coordinates.
```